# Chaining futures with tuple types

Tags: vapor

I am frequently needing to pass multiple objects through a series of chained Futures. I have solved the issue with code similar to the below, but it doesn't feel 'right'. Is there a better way to write this?

In particular, the lines beginning `return map(to:` don't smell right, as I'm taking an actual value `a` then turning it into a Future `conn.future(a)` just to be later flatMapped again in the next step.

In the contrived example below, we are creating an `A`, with a related object `B`, and optionally a `C` which is related to `B`, which is why `B` must be passed through the chain.

```
class A {
  id: Int?
}
class B {
  id: Int?
  aId: Int?
}
class C {
  id: Int?
  bId: Int?
}

/// Creates an A and B, with an optionally attached C. Returns the A.
func create(withC: Bool, on conn: MySQLConnection) throws -> Future<A> {
  return try A.create(on: conn)
    // Returning two futures
    .flatMap(to: (A, B).self) { a in
      let futureB = try B(aId: a.requireID()).create(on: conn)
      return map(to: (A, B).self, conn.future(a), futureB) { ($0, $1) }
    }
    // Returning two futures, one optional
    .flatMap(to: (A, C?).self) { a, b in
      guard withC else {
        return map(to: (A, C?).self, conn.future(a), conn.future(nil)) { ($0, $1) }
      }
      let futureC = try C(bId: b.requireId()).create(on: conn)
      return map(to: (A, C?).self, conn.future(a), futureC) { ($0, $1) }
    }
    // Convert back to the future we care about
    .map(to: A.self) { a, _ in return a }
}
```